# Sum lists with different lengths in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I have 3 lists with different lengths. They are made like this:

```
final_list = [[1230, 0], [1231,0],[1232,0], [1233, 0], [1234, 0]]

list2 = [[1232, 20], [1233, 30]]
list3 = [[1230, 10], [1231,20],[1232,40]]
```

What I want to obtain the final_list like this:

```
final_list = [[1230, 10], [1231,20],[1232,60], [1233, 30], [1234, 0]]
```

(If, considering each element of list2 and list3, its first value is equal to one of the first elements of the final list, then the corresponding element of the final list has to have the second value equal to the sum of the elements found.)

Comment: Append, sort, group, add.

Comment: also you mighty want to use a dictionary instead

Answer (score 0):

Not a clean solution, but easy to grasp and might save your day.

```
f = {}
dcts = map(lambda l: dict([l]), list2+list3)
for dct in dcts:
    for k in dct.iterkeys():
        f[k] = w.get(k, 0) + d[k]
final_list = map(list, f.items())
```

however, if you are familiar with [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
import groupby from itertools

merged = list2+list3
final_list = []

for key, group in groupby(merged, key = lambda e: e[0]):
    final_list.append([key, sum(j for i, j in group)])
```

or a oneliner

```
[[k, sum(j for i, j in g)] for k, g in  groupby(list3+list2, key = lambda e: e[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a `temp_list` and append all three lists to it.
create a dictionary `dic` and loop through `temp_list` to sum up each tuple base on the key.
then I turn the `dic` back into a list and sort it.

I admit this is not the most efficient way to do this. but it is a solution.

```
temp_list = []
temp_list.append(final_list)
temp_list.append(list2)
temp_list.append(list3)

dic = {}

for lst in temp_list:
    for tp in lst:
        if tp[0] in dic:
            dic[tp[0]] = dic[tp[0]] + tp[1]
        else:
            dic[tp[0]] = tp[1]

result = []

for key, value in dic.iteritems():
    temp = [key,value]
    result.append(temp)

result.sort()
```

result:

`[(1230, 10), (1231, 20), (1232, 60), (1233, 30), (1234, 0)]`